# Application closes after taking picture on some devices

Tags: android

My app crash after taking picture on Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime Pro but work on other devices. I have tried to figure out why it could be so but just couldn't figure it out.

The video recording worked fine but don't know why picture is giving error.

This is what happened when taking picture:

When camera lunched and picture taken, when I clicked on **Ok** an error prompt out  saying **Appname has stopped**

Video is working well but when I snap picture and click ok to return it gives error.

below is my code for capturing image and video

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
                    capturedImageUri = data.getData();

                    if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
                    }else {
                        mediaFile = "";
                        mediaFile = getRealPathFromURIPath(capturedImageUri, EventActivity.this);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Capture image path" + mediaFile);
                        attachmentStatus.setText("Image file has been attached");
                        isImage = true;
                    }
                }
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE) {
                    videoUri = data.getData();

                    if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
                    }else{
                        videoFile = getRealPathFromURIPath(videoUri, EventActivity.this);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Captured video path " + videoUri);
                        Log.d(TAG, "New path " + videoFile);
                        attachmentStatus.setText("Video file has been attached");
                        isImage = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

 private void showOptionDialog(){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(EventActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("SELECT ACTION TO COMPLETE");
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.image_video_layout);

        final TextView takePhoto = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
        final TextView recordVideo = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.record_video);

        dialog.show();

        takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Take a picture");
                if(isLocationEnabled()){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
                }else{
                    showLocationAlert();
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        recordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Record a video");
                Intent videoCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                if(videoCaptureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                    startActivityForResult(videoCaptureIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Show exception log

Comment: @shmakova, no error shown in logCat. it happened on the phone alone and not on all phones.

Comment: If the app crashes there's a stacktrace in your Logcat unless you're running the app in release mode. Check your Logcat again.

Comment: The code should have at least basic exception handling, e.g. so that you don't call `data.getData()` if `data` is `null`. (I'm not sure if it can be null in this case, but it was just an example.) There could be a problem in `getRealPathFromURIPath()` just as well, but we don't know what's in there.